# Multi SIte Manager and Grid Field

Tags: multi-site-manager, grid

I'm using multi site manager to duplicate a site but when I create the site all the grid field types data are missing.

I used the option to duplicate channel and channel entries when creating the new site and other fields have copied correctly.

I'm using ExpressionEngine 2.9.2 and Multiple Site Manager 2.1.7.

Is there a issue with MSM and the grid field type?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when you duplicated the channel this did not automatically duplicate the exp_channel_grid_filed tables because that would not make any sense, as the entry_id(s) would be different.

Duplicating channels with grid fields is a little more complicated.  Take a look at your table structure in mySQL to see what has happened.
I hope that that helps you to see what you can do.